# Can I embed a Twitter post in my answer?

Tags: support, markdown, formatting, twitter

Shortly after asking *[How do I enable email notifications from Discord?](https://superuser.com/q/1237841/358766)*, I sent a tweet to Discord's official Twitter account asking for support. To my surprise, [I received a fairly quick response](https://twitter.com/discordapp/status/893643703465758720) stating that it was currently not possible to re-enable email notifications.

Since Discord's tweet is a fairly definitive response, there a way I can embed it as an answer to my question?

If tweet embedding isn't possible, how should I convey the relevant information? Should I use a screenshot or a quoteblock?

Comment: Take a screenshot of the tweet.

Comment: If you do take a screenshot, make sure you quote the text somewhere - whether as image alt/description text or below it. Some people are on connections where images are filtered out (especially because SE hosts them on imgur).

Answer (score 2):

I'd go with a self contained answer *referencing* the tweet.

A screenshot would be nice, but it would be as simple as

"I contacted the discord team via twitter - and [they responded](https://twitter.com/discordapp/status/893643703465758720), that it was currently...."

Of course if it got fixed its nice to follow up your answer.